# GET Request 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: node.js, angular, rest

In Postman the profile is authorized and a json object is returned.
But on the front-end, I'm getting this error.

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://localhost:3000/users/profile", ok: false, …}

Here is my auth.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

interface data{
  success: boolean;
  msg: string;
  token: string;
  user: any;
}

export class AuthService {

  authToken: any;
  user: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getProfile() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get<data>('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res);
  }

loadToken(){
    const Token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = Token;
  }
}
```

profile.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  user: Object;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile.user;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: try to console the value of `this.authToken` and check in network tab for request!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Tried doing that, I get the correct token which works on postman but not on the application.

Comment: I think its related to `CORS` , did you allow that in webAPI project?

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because this.loadToken() returns you the token. you have to wait till you this.loadToken() function returns you the authToken.

for this, you can use async and await for your function or else just return the value from this.loadToken like

```
getProfile() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.authToken = this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get<data>('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res);
  }

loadToken(){
    const Token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
     return Token;
  }
```

Comment: Made the changes, did not work. Still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help but try to enable CORS in your WebAPI project:

WebApiConfig.cs `(Register Method)`:

```
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: CORS is enabled in the project, the application used to work a few days ago. But I was using deprecated packages so I upgraded the CLI and started from scratch. Now it's not working and I think there's something wrong in the front-end of the application.